# How to Export report to Excel file in Jasper Reports

Tags: groovy, jasper-reports

I am using jasper reports and groovy/grails and i want to export report in "Excel" Format ,Basically an excel file has to generated and it can be downloaded by the user .how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about Grrovy, we use to do it in Java using xls exporter, there must be similar explorter for you.

Comment: can you tell me how to do in java

Comment: See it [Here](http://p2p.wrox.com/j2ee/38785-exporting-data-into-excel-using-jasper-reports.html)